# Como colocar links/tags html no models.TextField

Tags: django

Opa gente, tudo com vcs?

Tenho um campo description e ele é um TextField, como faço para formatar um link nele ? (deixar bonitinho) tentei colocar tags html mas ele n aceita.

models.py:

```
description = models.TextField()
```

No django admin:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No template renderizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que aparecesse o link bonitinho mas ele n reconhece a tag

Comment: Acho que vc não entendeu a pergunta, vou refazela.

Comment: Já tentou com `safe` na renderização? algo como `{{conteudo|safe}}` ?

Comment: Opa, tive que ver os filtros um por um e achei o safe, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce precisa dizer ao django que esse HTML e "confiavel" para isso voce pode fazer:

{{ seu_model.description | safe }}
Que o django ira renderizar.